# What is this error when deploying a Flask Application to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask app I was trying to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It failed so I checked the "eb-engine.log". There were two lines in it that are confusing. The first line says success, but the next line says failure but doesn't clearly indicate which file or directory does not exist.

**Line 1:**

```
2021/06/13 18:00:04.500111 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
```

**Line 2:**

```
2021/06/13 18:00:04.500795 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/eb-flask/virt/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

(which file or directory?)

The directory structure in the eb-flask.zip file certainly has the path /virt/bin/python so it's unclear why this deployment failed. The root of the zip file is "eb-flask".

When uncompressed, I can run the application.py file so the app itself runs. The "site-packages" folder matches the folder in PyCharm.

Beyond the long days spent and many, many re-tries, I'm out of ideas.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: So you bundle your own python with `eb-flask.zip`?

Comment: I zipped up the directory created and uploaded that to EB.